# Locking the Android UI

Tags: lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, locked-out, bugs, smart-lock

I'm running Android Nougat. I would like to know whether there is a way to lock the device while watching a YouTube video or doing some other critical operation so that you don't accidentally kick yourself or of the application or page your viewing in the process.

Ideally a slider button with a lock would be ideal here.

What about newer versions of Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Screen pinning. That way only YouTube (or any app) pinned on the screen will be visible, and you won't by mistake start another app.

Settings -> Security -> Screen pinning. Set it to On.